# Why may Harlan Thrombey not have included his mother in his will?

Tags: plot-explanation, knives-out

After Harlan Thrombey’s alternate will is enacted in the days following his death in *Knives Out*, it is unclear what the future holds for his very elderly mother, who was not mentioned in this will. All of Harlan’s family have been excluded from the will, however in Mrs Thrombey’s case, it is unclear for what reason.

Is it reasonable to assume that Mrs Thrombey lived in her son Harlan’s mansion? Does Richard’s red herring (related to potentially putting Mrs Thrombey in a nursing home) have any credence? Can anything be deduced about her financial position in the wake of Harlan’s death?